# Intersect 2 lists, store result in a tuple in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I thought what I had was a common problem, but I could not find any help either in Google nor in SO.

I have 2 lists that contain objects of class `Marker`. A `Marker` consists of variables `name`, `position` and `type`. I want to intersect the two lists, create tuples of markers of the same type and store them in a new list. Literally speaking, I want to do something like the following:

```
g_markerList = [ (marker1,marker2) for marker1 in marker1List and marker2 in marker2List if marker1.type == marker2.type ]
```

Apparently, this code does not work. Compiler does not ''know'' variable `marker2` following `and`, which ends the `for` clause.

Please help me to intersect these two lists and obtain a list of tuples of similar markers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the `and` to `for`:

```
g_markerList = [ (marker1,marker2) for marker1 in marker1List
                                   for marker2 in marker2List
                                   if marker1.type == marker2.type ]
```

Comment: I have one more question. The list that I construct in this manner is a permutation, but not an intersection, i.e. each marker from list 1 is coupled with each  marker from the list2 where both markers share the same type. As a result, one marker is present in the list more than once. How can I take each marker only once?

Comment: add them to a `set`.  Multiple additions of the same object in a `set` get ignored.
For that matter, sets have an `intersection` method and operator (`&`) you could use, except that you want to do the comparison based on a projection of the two collections.  Not sure how to do that in python.  That'd be a worthwhile (I'd vote it up) question.